# Android:Listview row background color changing on scroll

Tags: android

This is my code

```
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;  

        if(view==null)
        {
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.citylist, parent, false);       
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);    
            holder.txtTitle.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,db.getSettings().getInt(15)-3);
            holder.txtTitle.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);                     
            view.setTag(holder);        
        }
        else{       
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();       
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(data.get(position));
        if(position % 2 == 0)view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 224, 235));
        return view;
   }
```

when i scroll the color on even row is also appearing on odd row help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view in the list is recycled. That's the item view scrolled outside to the screed is reused in the item scrolled into the screen. So you need to set the odd item a normal color like this.

```
if(position % 2 == 0)view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 224, 235));
if(position % 2 == 1)view.setBackgroundColor(The normal color you should set);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

`if(position % 2 == 0)view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(224, 224, 235));`

to

`view.setBackgroundColor(position & 1 == 0 ? Color.rgb(224, 224, 235) : android.R.color.transparent);`